# SQL Data Tools: Schema view showing Synonyms as Tables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Using SSDT in VS2012 I have created a number of synonyms from a reporting db to a transactional db.

When viewing the schema view - the synonyms appear under the *tables* subdir, with the SQLCMD variables as part of the table name.

I can kind-of understand the logic of this, however it does pollute the layout and makes it harder to find the tables I'm looking for?

nb.  I cant expand any of these tables (ie they dont show the columns of the synonym) and there is no option to delete (right click only gives Refresh and properties)

[image]

Hmmm...  Looking further at this it seems there are more issues with the schema view.  The image below shows the *views* of the reference database. (there is no actual reference to these views in the database itself) - it also shows the views of the Master Database (which is also a db reference in the project?)

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure you can rename them if you want to. They're just files so the actual functionality is in the content, not the name. You can move them to a separate folder for synonyms if you'd like. It won't do that for you in the future, but it could clean up your projects for current use.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Schott, but this is the _schema_ view (in the **SQL Object Explorer** view) and I don't get the option to rename them as they are not files.   I've just discovered related problems and will update the question

Comment: Well, for external references (like master), you can click the "Projects" folder, then at the top click the "Show Results" button and turn off external objects. That will help with not showing objects in your referenced databases.

Comment: Do you have any default values for the SQLCMD variables set in your .sqlproj properties? Compares can use the values set in the project, and can often have issues resolving them properly if there's nothing there.